# How to extract "TX packets" from ifconfig

Tags: bash, shell

I want to read the TX packets count into a variable with bash. On the shell I can extract it with `$ ifconfig eth0| grep "TX packets" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d ":" -f2` so I tried to lay this down in a script and came up with:

```
2: #!/bin/bash
3: 
4: THRESHOLD=1000
5: ADAPTER="eth0"
6: IFSTR="TX packets"
7: AWKCMD= "\'\{print \$2\}\'"
8: CUTCMD="-d \":\" -f2"
9: CMD="ifconfig $ADAPTER | grep $IFSTR | awk $AWKCMD | cut $CUTCMD"
10: echo $CMD
```

now it keeps complaining about the AWKCMD line:

```
/home/ron/scripts/keepup.sh: line 7: \'\{print $2\}\': command not found                                                             
ifconfig eth0 | grep TX packets | awk | cut -d ":" -f2
```

How do I get bash to correctly interpret this as a variable?

Comment: Ideally? Don't. It's much easier and more reliable to get the number straight from procfs (which is where ifconfig gets it from anyhow).

Comment: That said, your *bug* here is explained -- in detail -- in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: (By the way -- don't use all-caps variable names. By [POSIX-specified convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), those are reserved for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system -- your own variables should have at least one lower-case character to ensure that they can't conflict with a name having meaning to the system).

Comment: Another issue is that you have a space around `=`, the assignment.

Comment: @codeforester, ...immediate issue, yes. Only issue, of course, not so much. (I'm trying to figure out whether to answer the titular question with something sysfs-based, or treat it as "why doesn't my method work?" and close it as a duplicate of another BashFAQ #50 violation).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so, would something like `$ cat /proc/net/dev | grep eth0 | awk '{print $11}'` be the correct way to get the value, instead?

Comment: @cerr, `awk '/eth0/ { print $11 }' </proc/net/dev` is a much more efficient way to write that (only one process, not a full pipeline). But I'd need to check the docs for `/proc/net/dev` to know if its ordering is guaranteed; personally, I'd go with the sysfs approach given in my answer, vs procfs. (Couldn't edit the answer to correct myself above due to the 5-minute edit window)

Comment: @cerr, ...see [the Useless Use Of `cat` Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) as a little piece of Internet history. :)

Comment: (BTW, jumping back to the *immediate* issue -- http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught it; it's often worth running code through there before asking questions here).

Comment: All good stuff above, I would add that putting code into variables (`AwkCmd`, `CutCmt`, `Cmd` (!wth!) ) is almost always an invitation to hair-tearing. If you need to parameterize your code, use `awk -v dt="2017-03-18"` and other techniques depending on the tool. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your kernel is Linux, you're best off asking the kernel to give you the number you want itself:

```
adapter=eth0
tx_packets=$(</sys/class/net/"$adapter"/tx_packets) || {
  echo "Could not find $adapter" >&2; exit 1
}
echo "Adapter $adapter sent $tx_packets packets"
```

That way you aren't reliable on a tool that's likely to go away in the future. (`ifconfig` on Linux has been unmaintained for over a decade now in favor of the iproute2 suite). Moreover, sysfs is where `ifconfig` is getting the numbers from itself -- so you're cutting out quite a range of middlemen by going there directly.

---

As for your attempt at a script, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a full, detailed description of why it failed and how to reuse code without putting that code in strings. Personally, *if* I were going to parse `ifconfig`'s output in that way, I might write:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- pipefail not guaranteed to work with /bin/sh, so use bash here!

set -o pipefail # ensure that pipeline fails if ifconfig does

adapter="eth0"
tx_packets=$(ifconfig "$adapter" | awk '/TX packets/ {print $2}' | cut -d ":" -f2) || exit

echo "Adapter $adapter sent $tx_packets packets"
```

However, I *wouldn't* advise parsing `ifconfig`'s output at all.

Note that this output format is not standardized across operating systems, so you can't rely on the popularity of that name (for OS-specific interface configuration tools) to imply that output format will comply with any particular standard.

Comment: Thanks for the script, in Ubuntu 22.04 it should be changed to `/sys/class/net/"$adapter"/statistics/tx_packets`